# Is there any data Visualization technique which will recommend us to do feature scaling?

Tags: data-science

In the process of applying an algorithm in data science , we need to do feature scaling on input data set. I would like to know whether is it mandatory step or is there any technique which will decide to perform feature scaling

1) Data Visualization
2) Statistical values

Answer (score 0):

Feature scaling is needed if your inputs have a wide range of variation, if they are already normalized then you don't need it.
There is not a precise rule to follow. As a basic rule consider that normalized inputs work better then non normalized ones.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a model with two numerical features and suppose one is having high values, like salary, (e.g. 2345, 1756, 34521 etc) and one is having low values, like age, (e.g. 33, 17, 29 etc). Obviously the numerical feature with higher values will have clear impact on model.

So to avoid this, we should scale both features to same level and do the modeling.

And it depends on the algorithm you are using to build the model. Only few models need feature scaling, not all.